# DateTimePicker with date, hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetimepicker

I am working on a system where I am asked to set an exact time point with this format dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss, the problem is that I can't find a way to add a datetimepicker that contains all that at once, The component MUI's DateTimePicker is very ugly, and I like the native datepicker (it's the one I'd like to use) but I've only been able to choose the full date, hours, minutes but not seconds. Is there a way to do it? So far my code is like this (I also attach an image of the result):

```
<TextField
 id="datetime-local"
 label="Next appointment"
 type="datetime-local"
 defaultValue={ new Date() }
 InputLabelProps={{shrink: true,}}
/>
```

[This is what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkqES.png)

Answer (score 3):

material-ui has pickers: @material-ui/pickers

You can use it with `format` option:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { DateTimePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';

function App() {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
      <DateTimePicker format="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" value={selectedDate} onChange={handleDateChange} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I am avoiding using the material component because the way to select the time does not seem practical to me. I attached an image, so you can see how I would like it to look. On the other hand, format="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" will not give me the possibility to select seconds, which is something else I would like.

Comment: @LuisSandoval,
You can try:
 defaultValue={ "2017-05-24T10:30:14"}

but it won't let you clicking on seconds in the input and enter number manually.
If you like it, you only need to format the new date into the format above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Precisely now I need a date time picker that allows me to select date, hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can incorporate these views within your DesktopDateTimePicker component as follows:

```
  <DesktopDateTimePicker
      views={['year','month','day','hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']} />
```

This configuration allows users to select years, months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds within the DesktopDateTimePicker component.